# How to extend functionalities of a tf.data.TextLineDataset class?

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

I'm loading a CSV file and I want to customize a tf.data.TextLineDataset to implement a map function depending on the attribute of the class itself. For example, I want to remove the minimum value of the previously drawn items. The only way I have found is something like

```
class myDataSet(tf.data.TextLineDataset):
__slots__ = ['dim', 'batch_size', 'shuffle', 'tmin', 'finaldataset']

def __init__(self, batch_size=5, dim=14,
             shuffle=True, filepath="test.csv"):
    super(myDataSet, self).__init__([filepath])

    self.dim = dim
    self.batch_size = batch_size
    self.shuffle = shuffle

    self.tmin = tf.Variable(initial_value=[10.])

    self.finaldataset = self.skip(1)

    self.finaldataset = self.finaldataset.repeat()
    self.finaldataset = self.finaldataset.shuffle(10 * self.batch_size)
    self.finaldataset = self.finaldataset.prefetch(20 * self.batch_size)

    self.finaldataset = self.finaldataset.batch(self.batch_size) 
    self.finaldataset = self.finaldataset.map(self.parsefn, num_parallel_calls=8)

def parsefn(self, tf_string):
    data = tf.decode_csv(tf_string, record_defaults=[[0.]] * self.dim)

    input_tens = data[:-1]
    target_tens = data[-1]

    input_tens = tf.stack(input_tens , axis=-1)

    self.tmin = 0.8 * self.tmin + 0.2 * tf.reduce_min(target_tens, axis=0)

    target_tens = target_tens - self.tmin

    return input_tens, target_tens

def getminmax(self):
    return self.tmin
```

This code works, even if it is not so elegant to me because I have a finaldataset inside myDataSet. However, I cannot access the value of tmin from the main code. In fact,

```
sess.run(datasetG.getminmax())
```

throws the following error:

```
Fetch argument <tf.Tensor 'add:0' shape=(2,) dtype=float32> cannot be interpreted as a Tensor.
```

How can I read this attribute? Thanks a lot

-- EDIT --

This is the code running before calling datasetG.getminmax()

```
with tf.device('/cpu:0'):
datasetG = datamanagement.myDataSet(batch_size=5, dim=2,
             shuffle=True, filepath="AB_fit.csv")

iterG = datasetG.finaldataset.make_initializable_iterator()

elG = iterG.get_next()

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.initializers.global_variables())
    sess.run(iterG.initializer)
    print(sess.run(elG))
    sess.run(datasetG.getminmax())
```

Comment: Can you post the part of the code before executing `sess.run(datasetG.getminmax())`?

Comment: Yes, of course. I've just edited the question

Comment: Still, I can't reproduce the error. Can you provide a small example that doesn't include csv files so that I can reproduce the error you are getting?